# anaconda python running py file

Tags: python, anaconda

I downloaded python anaconda 2.7.
I used to work with the regular python from python.org, but I was asked to work with anaconda.
any how, I have 2 problems.

1. right click ->edit with idle (does not exist).
2. can't run py file as a program (like cmd)/.

Comment: Ok? We can’t really do much with that info... have you googled the problem?

Comment: yes of course. didn't find any good one. Is there any deffrent between the two apps?

Comment: 1)You can install an IDE like spyder
2)You can use anaconda console to run the .py file OR you have to activate the virtual environment if you are using any.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Anaconda, mostly the path environment variable is overridden hence the system now refers to the Anaconda python interpreter, a quick fix is to correct the path environment (this depends on the type of OS you're running).